# Do you know where can I found this broken wall Photoshop frame?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've been looking for this frame for a while but I just cant find it anywhere.
I could find the inner picture but I'd like to use the frame.
I was able to remove the picture but the frame is low quality so its not good for me.

[image: Frame]

Comment: Try searching a stock photography/art website, such as shutterstock, istockphoto, dreamstime, adobe stock, etc.

Comment: Thank you,i've been searching on adobe creative cloud for a while and i also posted this on freelancers sites.

Answer (score 2):

Do it yourself, it's not that hard

- Place a White Color fill on top with an irregular Mask. I use your image and select the white with the Magic Wand Tool.
- Find several backgrounds and put them in different layers
- Draw an irregular frame with the Polygonal Lasso Tool and create a Mask to each of them
- Duplicate some of them and transform the mask
- Add some drop shadow effect
- Put the main image as a background, photo from [unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/photos/mWYhrOiAgmA)
- Add an Inner Glow Effect to give depth > Black > Multiply

[image: Wall]

Comment: how do you make the 'irregular mask' shape?

Comment: Copy-paste the question sample image > Photoshop Magic Wand Tool.  The others with the Polygonal Lasso Tool.

Comment: Ah, nice method. You might want to add that to your answer, it's a hard part of the process imho and you kind of gloss over it :)